# How do I set key bindings for ctrl page up and ctrl page down in gnu screen?

Tags: gnu-screen

So ctrl page up and down are all the rage nowadays, and I'd like to be able to C-p and C-n in gnu screen when I hit ctrl-pgup and down.
I've tried and tried but the documentation is a little thin.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turns out you can do it. I finally figured it out.

With the help of this...

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/76566/where-do-i-find-a-list-of-terminal-key-codes-to-remap-shortcuts-in-bash

I add this to `~/.screenrc`:

```
bindkey -t ^[[5;7~ prev
bindkey -t ^[[6;7~ next
```

and that gets me <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>PageUp/Down</kbd> moves between screen tabs.

Comment: this one is handy too. ctrl-alt t for make a new screen   bindkey -t ^[^T screen

Comment: For alt/page{up,down}, change the `;7~` to `;3~` in the snippet.

Comment: And for Ctrl + Page[Up|Down] change `;7~` to `;5~`.

Comment: Found it, -t stands there for the key code, you can use ;2~ for the SHIFT key. Thank you!

Comment: This binding scrolls between the contents of screen windows in multi window screen scenario (I guess because of the prev-next commands).
If you want to scroll the contents of the actual screen windows I've found this https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/46483/how-to-allow-page-up-in-gnu-screen

Answer (score 4):

A <kbd>control</kbd><kbd>pageup</kbd> depends upon the particular terminal, but most of the ones you are interested in copy one of the flavors from xterm.  Those look like

```
^[[5;5~
```

or in terminfo format

```
\E[5;5~
```

That is 6 characters.

However, screen (see [14.1 The bind command](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/html_node/Bind.html#Bind) from screen's manual) says that it only knows how to bind a single character.

So the answer is: you cannot do that with screen.

Comment: I tried some more and I think you can do it (bindkey allows multiple characters) but what I didn't realize is that ctrl-pgup/dn never make it to the terminal because my xfce terminal grabs them for itself.

Comment: See my answer, you can...

Answer (score 3):

You can define it easily using the [`bindkey` command](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/html_node/Bindkey.html):

```
bindkey -t <key-code> <command>
```

It allows you to map any key to any command. For switching to the previous and next window, use commands `prev` and `next`.

The key code for <kbd>PageDown</kbd> is `^[[5~` and <kbd>PageUp</kbd> `^[[6~`, so to switch windows using those two keys, add the following to your `~/.screenrc` configuration:

```
bindkey -t ^[[5~ prev
bindkey -t ^[[6~ next
```

To add the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> modifier, add `;5` to the key code:

```
bindkey -t ^[[5;5~ prev
bindkey -t ^[[6;5~ next
```

For the <kbd>Alt</kbd> modifier, add `;3` and for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd>, add `;7`.

The `-t` parameter disables the timer so there may be a time gap between the presses of the individual keys.

### Finding Out Key Codes

It's possible that on different systems or terminals, key codes may be different. To find out the exact codes, execute [`showkey -a`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/showkey) and press the keys or key combinations of your interest, the program will print their codes in the first column.

Comment: I've spent some minutes pressing ALT, SHIFT, CAPS, CTRL to no result ...
ENTER and other keys worked though.
Don't forget to press PgUp or PgDn in conjunction with these keys :rotfl:
anyway, here is the list of codes I've amassed
# ;2~ stands for ANSI SHIFT
# ;3~ stands for ANSI ALT
# ;4~ stands for ANSI SHIFT+ALT
# ;5~ stands for ANSI CTRL
# ;6~ stands for ANSI CTRL+SHIFT
# ;7~ stands for ANSI CTRL+ALT
# ;8~ stands for ANSI CTRL+ALT+SHIFT

Answer (score 1):

The title text in the question asks about ctrl+pageup and ctrl+pagedown, but the selected answer mentions alt+ctrl. Here's how xterm reads ctrl+pageup and ctrl+pagedown.

in `~/.screenrc`:

```
# ctrl+pgup = prev
bindkey -t ^[[5;5~ prev
# ctrl+pgdn = next
bindkey -t ^[[6;5~ next
```

Comment: if you look down a few answers somebody pointed out you can't do that with screen, so I came up with something that yields a usable result with ctrl-alt which I could do with screen

Comment: @stu What version of gnu screen are you using? And what terminal? I use this on multiple different computers, copied from my `~/.screenrc`, and it works fine.

Comment: whatever comes with ubuntu 1604. if I remember right, it might not be screen as much as the terminal I'm using that grabs the keystrokes before they get to screen.